# PHP - Mysqli Connection open and close using object oriented way - MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to find a way which does the following

- Object Oriented way
- Closing the connection efficiently
- closing a connection anyways

  ```
  <?php 

   define("HOST", "localhost");
   define("USER", "username");
   define("PASS", "password");
   define("DBNM", "database");

   class ConnectionTest extends mysqli {

      private $link;

      function __construct() {
          $this->link = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASS, DBNM);
      }

      function getLink(){
          return $this->link;
      }

      function __destruct() {
          mysqli_close($this->link)
      }
   }
  ?>
  ```

To try to get to my objective

1. Object Oriented way - Used a class
2. closing connection efficiently - defined a function to close the connection
3. closing a connection anyways - set the same function to be destructor of that class

As I am new to PHP, I would like to know:

- Is this technique proper?
- What complications could occur? or what are the disadvantages to this technique?
- Is there any improvement needed in this code?

Comment: The connection is closed anyway at the end of the script.

Comment: @Qirel Thanks, i got that my class is completely useless. As MySQLi  class does the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly, this class of yours makes very little sense as it effectively duplicates mysqli. All the things you want to achieve, are already implemented in mysqli:

1. Object Oriented way - Mysqli is a class already.
2. There is a function in mysqli to close a connection as well
3. Which is closing a connection efficiently.

So I fail to see how is your class any better than mysqli.

Comment: from your reply, I assume MySQLi does close the connection automatically and is object oriented anyways. so this class is useless. This post was just for information anyways. Thanks again.